# generating dynamic nested json using angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

```
import { EmpAttendance } from './attendance.model';

export class Employee {
    id: number;
    Name: string;
    Gender: string;
    Email?: string;
    phoneNumber?: number;
    ContactPreference: string;
    DateOfBirth: Date;
    Department: string;
    IsActive: boolean;
    PhotoPath?: string;
    present?: boolean;
    leave?: boolean;
    holiday?: boolean;
    Attendance?: EmpAttendance[];

    constructor(
        id: number,
        Name: string,
        Gender: string,
        ContactPreference: string,
        DateOfBirth: Date,
        Department: string,
        IsActive: boolean,
        Email?: string,
        phoneNumber?: number,
        PhotoPath?: string,
        present?: boolean,
        leave?: boolean,
        holiday?: boolean,
        Attendance?: EmpAttendance[],
   ) {
       this.id = id;
       this.Name = Name;
       this.Gender = Gender;
       this.ContactPreference = ContactPreference;
       this.DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth;
       this.Department = Department;
       this.IsActive = IsActive;
       this.Email = Email;
       this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
       this.PhotoPath = PhotoPath;
       this.present = present;
       this.leave = leave;
       this.holiday = holiday;
       this.Attendance = Attendance;
    }
}

export class EmpAttendance {
    constructor(public date: string, public AttendanceValue: string){
    }
}
```

Above are the model of my employee object.I have performed the basic Crud operation and here is a copy of db.json file

```
{
    "employees": [{
        "id": 1,
        "Name": "jayanth",
        "Gender": "male",
        "ContactPreference": "phone",
        "phoneNumber": "9515231427",
        "Email": "jayanth@datawavetechnologies.com",
        "DateOfBirth": "1995-01-29T18:30:00.000Z",
        "Department": "1",
        "IsActive": true,
        "PhotoPath": "assets/Images/MaleEmployee.jpg",
    }]
}
```

Now I want to take the Attendance of each employee existing and here is what I have tried with my employee.service.ts:

```
patchAdd(empId: number, itemToAdd: EmpAttendance): Observable<Employee> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${empId}`;
    return this._HttpClient.patch<Employee>(url, itemToAdd).pipe(catchError(this.handleErrors));
}
```

In My employee-attendance.component.ts(After clicking save button):

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.employee.length; i++) {
    if (this.employee[i].IsActive == true && this.employee[i].present == true) {
        const newItem = new EmpAttendance(this.selectedDate, "present");
        this._EmployeeService.patchAdd(this.employee[i].id, newItem).subscribe(
            response => {
                response.Attendance.push(newItem); // Values were perfectly adding to attendance property as what I needed. But added data getting lost when page reloads and not reflecting in db.json file  
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.Name) + " " + JSON.stringify(response.Attendance));
            }
        );
    }
}
```

After doing the above operation my db.json file looks like this and if I perform multiple times date and AttendanceValue properties keeps on updating(may be due to patch method)

```
{
    "employees": [{
        "id": 1,
        "Name": "jayanth",
        "Gender": "male",
        "ContactPreference": "phone",
        "phoneNumber": "9515231427",
        "Email": "jayanth@datawavetechnologies.com",
        "DateOfBirth": "1995-01-29T18:30:00.000Z",
        "Department": "1",
        "IsActive": true,
        "PhotoPath": "assets/Images/MaleEmployee.jpg",
        "date": "2020-08-08T08:11:51.000Z",
        "AttendanceValue": "present"
    }]
}
```

I need db.json in this format....pls...plsss...plssssss help me in getting this

```
{
    "employees": [{
        "id": 1,
        "Name": "jayanth",
        "Gender": "male",
        "ContactPreference": "phone",
        "phoneNumber": "9515231427",
        "Email": "jayanth@datawavetechnologies.com",
        "DateOfBirth": "1995-01-29T18:30:00.000Z",
        "Department": "1",
        "IsActive": true,
        "PhotoPath": "assets/Images/MaleEmployee.jpg",
        "Attendance": [
            {
                "date": "2020-06-13T09:00:34.000Z",
                "AttendanceValue": "present"
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-08-08T08:11:51.000Z",
                "AttendanceValue": "present"
            }
        ],
    }]
}
```

Comment: If you need to add user data into db.json then you need to write on the db.json file to save it.

Comment: @KamranKhatti Hii Sir..Thanks for the comment..But that is not my question.I Just want to know how a nested json object values can be added "dynamically"....Not by entering manually in db.json file

Comment: If you have any stackblitz demo then I can have better idea and fix the issue.

Comment: @KamranKhatti Sorry sirr....I never went to it and I am working on local host..But I can say that the entire code is fine...I am just failing to give perfect logic in employee-attendance.component.ts at lines where I have showcased above

Comment: What saying that on page reload value disapear and never reflect in db.json this is expected until you need to write values in db.json or permanently store in session or localstorage or database.

Comment: @KamranKhatti thats what my question is.."How to?" generate dynamic NESTED JSON in db.json(database)

Comment: For database you need to call API and store `response` in database.

Comment: @KamranKhatti thats what I mentioned in employee.service.ts(how I called the API for saving attendance(nested json object))...also employee-attendance.component.ts..(How I tried to store the response)

Comment: Try `const newItem =  new EmpAttendance([{date: this.selectedDate, AttendanceValue: "present"}])`

Comment: Noo sirr....It didn't help me....Both values were getting accepted correctly by this way const newItem = new EmpAttendance(this.selectedDate, "present");

Comment: Also If I pick some another date and submit for the second time..response.Attendance.push(newItem); is adding the second values with the previous one(but on the console)...In the db.json first values were getting replaced by second values..

Comment: Put your stuff on stackblitz I can fix there here no idea just assumptions.